# Ubuntu 18.04 network icon disappeared and no internet access in VMware

Tags: networking, network-manager, icons, vmware

Im using Ubuntu in VMWare14. I have a 2 virtual machine, Ubuntu 14.04.02 and Ubuntu 18.04.1. They all works well before.

Today the network icon disappeared in Ubuntu 18.04.1, and I cant access internet. Ubuntu 14.04.02 still works well. Linked screen shot picture show icon disappear and I cant find the network option in settings.

Whats wrong? How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

[image: network icon disappear in ubuntu 18]

[image: settings no network in ubuntu 18]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0200]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'; LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show` (guest system) and a screenshot of the VM’s virtual network configuration (host system)? Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I solved the problem by command `nmcli network on`. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and that command solved it. But this leaves me with the question: What exactly is `nmcli` and what was the core of the problem?

Comment: Felt the same way as @thomaskonrad and expanded the post just a touch.

Comment: May be trivial, but I had to run 'nmcli network off' and then 'nmcli network on', to get it working.