# Wifi icon disappear, no internet iwlwifi errors

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

### The Problem

The wifi icon suddenly disappears, leaving me with no internet access. This has happened about 3 times in the last week, and doesn't seem to be triggered by anything I do. Last one (the one I'm copying the `dmesg` results) was caused while I was working on emacs (had a couple inactive tabs opened in firefox).

### Attempted solutions

I visited [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075139/ubuntu-18-04-network-icon-disappeared-and-no-internet-access-in-vmware) but my case is not related to vmware and the solution in the answer didn't work for me (`nmcli network on`, not even when preceded by `nmcli network off`).

Immediately after the last case I run `dmesg -HT` and saw some errors associated to `iwlwifi`, so I went to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990363/how-to-load-iwlwifi-driver) and tried to load the driver, to no avail.

I also looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327955/no-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-9462), but my firmware seems to be up-to-date:

```
stat -c %y /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
2021-10-09 11:47:13.854452373 -0500
```

The only thing that has worked for me is rebooting, and it is time consuming and really troublesome.

### Asking

What should I do to avoid this kind of problem?

### Context

I am running ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (from `lsb_release -a`) on an asus.

```
uname -a
Linux MachineName 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Results of `dmesg`:

```
dmesg -HT | grep -e '] iwlwifi' > ~/Desktop/error_iwlwifi.txt

[Fri Oct  8 19:35:32 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[Fri Oct  8 19:35:32 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[Fri Oct  8 19:35:32 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 24fd8086 00100000 02800078 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01108086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 001b0c10 0045e811 10110000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000005 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40000001
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000120: 0000000f ef100460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ff190dcf dc8b28ff 15410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40000001
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f ef100460 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.5) config registers:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000000: 9d158086 00100407 060400f1 00810010 00000000 00000000 00020200 200000f0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000020: ef10ef10 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0012020a
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000040: 01428010 00008001 0010000f 06724c13 70110042 004cb200 01480000 00000008
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000060: 00000000 00000837 00000000 0000000e 00010003 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000080: 00019005 fee00258 00000000 00000000 0000a00d 13111043 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000000a0: c8030001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 07001001 00001842 099e0008 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000000e0: 00e30300 88568856 00100006 00000000 00000150 4c000000 08410fb3 02000004
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000100: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000140: 2001000d 0000000f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000160: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000200: 2201001e 00b0281f 40a0280f
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.5) AER cap structure:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:12 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 11 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [155, 64] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:18 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: regular scan timed out
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending SCAN_ABORT_UMAC: time out after 2000ms.
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 255 write_ptr 0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: -1346793048
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.77d01142.0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x611E33A4 | branchlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000712 | interruptlink1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0552590 | interruptlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | data1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | beacon time
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | tsf hi
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | time gp2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFF13 | uCode version major
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode version minor
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xAEAE3415 | hw version
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | board version
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x81007740 | isr0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | isr1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000018 | isr2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC057950D | isr4
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | last cmd Id
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x81007750 | wait_event
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | l2p_control
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000028 | l2p_duration
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | l2p_mhvalid
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x810077D0 | l2p_addr_match
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | lmpm_pmg_sel
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x81007770 | timestamp
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | flow_handler
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC057950D | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | umac branchlink1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x81007750 | umac branchlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | umac interruptlink1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000028 | umac interruptlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | umac data1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x810077D0 | umac data2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | umac data3
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x81007770 | umac major
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | umac minor
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0E0D3B00 | frame pointer
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB5BA25B8 | stack pointer
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x9FEC9E88 | last host cmd
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | isr status reg
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:30 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000010, count: 1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.77d01142.0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC048BA9E | trm_hw_status0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000713 | trm_hw_status1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0552590 | branchlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | interruptlink1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | interruptlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | data2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | beacon time
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | tsf hi
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFF13 | time gp2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode revision type
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xAEAE3415 | uCode version major
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode version minor
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000010 | hw version
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | hcmd
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000018 | isr0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | isr2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x8529FC20 | isr4
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | last cmd Id
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC055503F | wait_event
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | l2p_control
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA1630018 | l2p_duration
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | l2p_mhvalid
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA1630018 | l2p_addr_match
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00A01C30 | timestamp
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x8529FC20 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFA9DE | umac branchlink1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC055503F | umac branchlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | umac interruptlink1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA1630018 | umac interruptlink2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | umac data1
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA1630018 | umac data2
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | umac data3
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00A01C30 | umac major
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xD1F02100 | frame pointer
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x140F5FBC | stack pointer
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x9FEC9E88 | last host cmd
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8E84 | isr status reg
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:33 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:35 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_tx_queues_empty bad state = 0
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:35 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:35 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[Fri Oct  8 20:40:35 2021] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
[Fri Oct  8 20:50:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[Fri Oct  8 20:50:37 2021] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
[Fri Oct  8 20:52:53 2021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[Fri Oct  8 20:52:53 2021] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Comment: "HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?" Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257107/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-it-was-working-properly-before-but-stopp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chili555 kindly suggested it was a hardware issue.

I just removed the card, placed it again and tighten the screw, and the problem has been gone for a full 48 hours.